# Docker compose up ECS error: Resource handler returned message: "Model validation failed (#/Volumes: array items are not unique)"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, prisma

I have been trying to deploy my Postgres + Backend + Prisma images to Amazon ECS but have been running into this error:

Resource handler returned message: "Model validation failed (#/Volumes: array items are not unique)"

I have been stuck on this for a couple of days and any help would be appreciated. I run **docker compose up** using my Amazon ECS context to get to this error.

```
version: '3.4'
    services:
      db:
        container_name: db
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        image: postgres:latest
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER=[user]
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=[password]
        volumes:
          - my-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data/2
      backend:
        depends_on:
          - db
        container_name: backend
        ports:
          - 4000:4000
        image: [backend image name]
      prisma:
        depends_on:
          - db
        container_name: prisma
        ports:
          - 5555:5555
        image: [prisma image name]
        environment:
          NODE_ENV: production
    volumes:
      my-vol:
```

Comment: Not related with the question, but one suggestion is that you don't need to expose ports of the services that won't face the internet, like 5432 or 4000.

Answer (score 1):

AWS container service team member here. I have never seen that error but there are a few things that don't seem right in the code above and that prevent me to be able to test it.

- services should be indented with version
- if I try to bring up (in AWS) Postgres with that volume mapping it spits an `"initdb: error: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty"` error. Postgres fails even if brought up locally on a docker host (with `docker-compose up`) albeit I did not investigate further there. Is there a reason why you have the `/2`? Is that supposed to work?
- You expose all services via the load balancer by specifying the `host:container` ports. I assume you only want the `prisma` container to be exposed? Or am I misinterpreting what you are doing?

This is a slightly modified version of your compose that seems to be working just fine for me:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=me
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
    volumes:
      - my-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  backend:
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: backend
    image: nginx
  prisma:
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: prisma
    ports:
      - 80:80
    image: nginx
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production  
volumes:
  my-vol:
```

Note I have just changed the prisma and backend container images with fake nginx images just for the purpose of bringing the stack up (I also had to change the port to `80:80`).

Comment: Is that not the right way to expose my Prisma port to the container? I want to be able to access the IP address with the port number [IP]:[port_number] so that's what I was thinking. I also use EXPOSE in the image Dockerfiles to expose the port, but something tells me that isn't the right way to do it.

Comment: You definitely need to call out the `ports` for the Prisma container if that is your stack endpoint (i.e. the service you want to expose). That way a "consumer" can reach the Prisma container, the Prisma container can talk to the backend container internally and the backend container can talk to postgres. But if you define `ports` for the other containers as well they will all be exposed to on the LB publicly (and I assume this is not what you want?)