# How to make Postgres containers shared data with amazon EFS?

Tags: database, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I have a cluster which has 2 instances.Both instance has Postgres container and its volume link to Elastic file system accesspoint as the Volume.

I map the volume of both instance to /var/lib/postgresql/data, but container didn't share its data.

Here is my configuration

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.0"
services:
    front:
        image: 540744822643.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/front:latest
        links:
            - app:app.plasgate.com
        networks:
            - app
        container_name: front
        environment:
            - NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=2048
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        logging:
            driver: awslogs
            options:
                awslogs-group: sms-gateway
                awslogs-region: ap-southeast-1
                awslogs-stream-prefix: "front"
    app:
        image: 540744822643.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/plasgate:latest
        links:
            - jasmin:jasmin
            - db:db
        networks:
            - app
        container_name: app
        environment:
            - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
            - PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
        restart: on-failure:10
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        logging:
            driver: awslogs
            options:
                awslogs-group: sms-gateway
                awslogs-region: ap-southeast-1
                awslogs-stream-prefix: "app"
    nginx:
        image: 540744822643.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/nginx:latest
        links:
            - app:app
            - front:front
        container_name: nginx
        networks:
            - app
        environment:
            API_HOST: "service.wpdevelop.xyz"
            API_PORT: 5000
            FRONT_HOST: "customer.wpdevelop.xyz"
            FRONT_PORT: 8080

        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        logging:
            driver: awslogs
            options:
                awslogs-group: sms-gateway
                awslogs-region: ap-southeast-1
                awslogs-stream-prefix: "nginx"
    db:
        image: 540744822643.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/postgres:latest
        volumes:
            - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
        restart: on-failure:10
        networks:
            - app
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "xxx@2020"
            POSTGRES_USER: webadmin
            POSTGRES_DB: smsgwdev
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        logging:
            driver: awslogs
            options:
                awslogs-group: sms-gateway
                awslogs-region: ap-southeast-1
                awslogs-stream-prefix: "db"
    redis:
        image: 540744822643.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/radis:latest
        container_name: redis
        restart: on-failure:10
        networks:
            - app
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
        logging:
            driver: awslogs
            options:
                awslogs-group: sms-gateway
                awslogs-region: ap-southeast-1
                awslogs-stream-prefix: "redis"
volumes:
    postgres:
networks:
    app:
        driver: bridge
```

ecs-params.yml

```
version: 1
task_definition:
    family: sms-gateway
    ecs_network_mode: bridge
    services:
        front:
            essential: true
            cpu_shares: 100
            mem_limit: 2147483648
            healthcheck:
                test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost || exit 1"]
                interval: 5s
                timeout: 10s
                retries: 3
                start_period: 30s
        app:
            essential: false
            cpu_shares: 100
            mem_limit: 2147483648
            healthcheck:
                test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:5000 || exit 1"]
                interval: 5s
                timeout: 10s
                retries: 3
                start_period: 30s
            depends_on:
                - container_name: db
                  condition: HEALTHY
        nginx:
            essential: false
            cpu_shares: 100
            mem_limit: 2147483648
            healthcheck:
                test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost || exit 1"]
                interval: 5s
                timeout: 10s
                retries: 3
                start_period: 30s
        db:
            essential: false
            cpu_shares: 100
            mem_limit: 2147483648
            healthcheck:
                test: pg_isready -U webadmin -d smsgwdev
                interval: 5s
                timeout: 10s
                retries: 2
                start_period: 30s
        redis:
            essential: false
            cpu_shares: 100
            mem_limit: 2147483648
            healthcheck:
                test: ["CMD-SHELL", "redis-cli", "ping"]
                interval: 5s
                timeout: 10s
                retries: 2
                start_period: 30s

    efs_volumes:
        - name: postgres
          filesystem_id: fs-a4aa73e4
          transit_encryption: ENABLED
          access_point: fsap-007405b3e9bc7bc2f
```

How can I make the two Postgres container use the same pgdata?

Answer (score 5):

First and foremost, running Postgres on EFS is not a great idea. I think it’s fine if you need something quick and for very low loads in test environments but EFS is not the right backend for a database engine. Second, sharing an EFS share between 2 containers is an even worse idea. This setup is a no-no because each database will get simultaneus non-arbitrated access to the same data files and this is not how Postgres is supposed to work.

Second, you don't call it out explicitly but are you using the `ecs-cli` to get this deployed? If so, my suggestion would be to look at an alternative mechanism we (AWS) have introduced together with Docker which relies on the [new Docker Compose capabilities to deploy to the Cloud (e.g. ECS)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/). The new version of the `ecs-cli` is called [Copilot](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/) and it moved away from Docker support. Note the new Docker Compose integration does not need a separate `ecs-params` file for now (albeit there are discussions to introduce one) and relies on `x-aws-` extensions in the docker compose file itself.

Third, regardless of whether this is a good idea or not (it’s not!) on the heels of and inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66915872/docker-compose-up-ecs-error-resource-handler-returned-message-model-validatio/66931769#66931769) example, the following simple compose allows you to deploy 2 x Postgres containers that share the same data directory:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  db1:
    container_name: db1
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=me
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
    volumes:
      - my-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  db2:
    depends_on:
      - db1
    container_name: db2
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=me
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
    volumes:
      - my-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  app:
    container_name: app
    image: nginx
volumes:
  my-vol:
```

If you `docker compose up` in an ECS context ([see the blog for more details](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/)) you will get 3 ECS services (1 x app/nginx and 2 x DB services) with the 2 DB services insisting on the same EFS Access Point. Again this is just an academic example to prove a working docker compose file. I DO NOT SUGGEST to use this in any meaningful deployment.

[UPDATE]: I have just noticed you only have 1 postgres in the compose above. So I assume you have two separate compose files with one postgres DB insisting against the same file system. All I said above still apply but note there is [a limitation that will prevent you to even technically deploy this scenario](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/1085).