# Updating only one container from an AWS instance deployed with Docker Compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I deployed a Postgres + Backend + Prisma instance to Amazon ECS using Docker compose. I have a question about updating an image without redeploying/deleting the entire instance.

My images are located on Amazon ECR - if I update the images on the Amazon ECR side, will that update my instance? The same link will still be used to reference my image so I was wondering if this is the case. If not, is there anyway for me to refresh only one container on the instance? I attached my docker-compose.yml file below.

```
version: '3.4'
    services:
      db:
        container_name: db
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        image: postgres:latest
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER=[user]
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=[password]
        volumes:
          - my-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data/2
      backend:
        depends_on:
          - db
        container_name: backend
        ports:
          - 4000:4000
        image: [backend image name]
      prisma:
        depends_on:
          - db
        container_name: prisma
        ports:
          - 5555:5555
        image: [prisma image name]
        environment:
          NODE_ENV: production
    volumes:
      my-vol:
```

Answer (score 0):

Glad you are [making progresses on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66915872/docker-compose-up-ecs-error-resource-handler-returned-message-model-validatio/66931769#66931769).

Merely updating the image on ECR won't do much because the ECS service won't be polling for new images. In native ECS, IF you force redeploy the service configured as-is AND IF you update the container image keeping the same `name:tag`, then it will re-deploy the tasks with the new image. I don't know if there is a way to force-redeploy via compose or if you would need to tweak/cheat the config in a way that tasks redeployments would be forced.

A way to achieve this would be to create a pipeline (with the tool of your convenience) that monitors for updates in ECR and, should a new image being uploaded, it would trigger a service redeployment.

A BETTER way to achieve this would be to create a pipeline (with the tool of your convenience) that does the same but works with different tags. It's not a best practice to always use the same tag for your deployments because you never know what's actually deployed at any point in time.

We wrote a [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/automated-software-delivery-using-docker-compose-and-amazon-ecs/) that covers some of these scenarios (including being able to build the container). If that is already done for you then the example in the blog should NOT be triggered by a new GH commit but by a new image being pushed to ECR.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will take a look on the blog post. I guess a good question to ask is this: would redeploying the entire instance delete my current Postgres service volume (my_vol)? I am wondering if doing so will clear out my Postgres image and hence delete the data already loaded onto that database.

Comment: No. The volume is never ever deleted. Even if you tear down (compose down) the entire stack. Please (PLEASE) do test your workflow and don't take my words for granted but we took the decision that not losing data was way more important than the annoyance of having to delete the EFS share out of band when you bring down the stack (or update it of course).

Comment: I didn't have much data to lose, but I just tried this out and my data was deleted. After checking the logs, I saw that the CREATE DATABASE command was sent so perhaps it cleared everything for me?

Comment: I should have been more precise. The EFS volume is not deleted. However if a container has logic that, at restarts or at some point, it wipes the data.... data will be wiped. Is this the standard Postgres container image you are using? I thought that HAD logic to avoid losing data if it finds existing DB(s) etc. Or maybe it's one of the application container that is resending the CREATE DB command?

Comment: I just checked and it doesn’t seem like the volume is being deleted. I’m not entirely sure on why it’s being restarted but I am using a standard Postgres image. Perhaps the POSTGRES_DB entry is restarting the DB but after looking online I didn’t think it should do that. I’ll keep looking into this and see what I can find.

Comment: Thanks. Please let us know. Also, probably unrelated, but when I tested your compose (see other thread I linked in my first answer here), the `my-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data/2` did not work. Are you able to make it work like that? Again maybe unrelated to what you are seeing now but I was curious when I saw it again here.